# normalize fft produced by fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d

Tags: fft, c++

`fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` takes an array for real numbers and produces an array of complex numbers 1/2 the size of input array + 1.

per fftw's website:

> As a result of this symmetry, half of the output Y is redundant (being the complex conjugate of the other half), and so the 1d r2c transforms only output elements 0...n/2 of Y (n/2+1 complex numbers), where the division by 2 is rounded down.

When I normalize do I normalize by the size of the fft or the resulting fft_size / 2

```
    // normalize the fft
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x <(fftSize/2); x++)
        array[x] = array[x] / complex<double>((fftSize/2), 0);   <<<<<
```

or

```
    // normalize the fft
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x <(fftSize/2); x++)
        array[x] = array[x] / complex<double>(fftSize, 0);       <<<<<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reading the manual](http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT.html#The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT), even though only half the data is returned, the full length FFT is calculated:

[image]

So you should normalize by whatever the full length is normalized to: `fft_size`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll admit I am much stronger once it's in the frequency domain.  Even after having read the above page over and over, I find that the transformation from time to frequency domains is a bit over my head.